# How to execute tasks in Celery using datetime from MySQL?

Tags: python, celery

News are stored in database MySQL with `datetime` of publication.

Any time user can add a new in the table with delay date publishing.

How to use Celery for listeting database table and check if it is time to publish data?

For publishing data is responsible another process(script Python). So Celery should call this script for each rows in MySQL table according `datetime`.

How to do that using Celery?

Another way I think to create queue with `date` and `id` of publication then directly add data from user form in this queue. Therefore sholud be process(Celery) that observes a queue for further executing tasks by date.

Celery provides documentation for Periodic tasks and Scheduled tasks, but there is no explanation and example how to use it.

Sorry if question is trivial, I am a newcomer in Python Celery.

Comment: You can schedule a daily task that publishes all publications whose publication date is `today()`

Comment: I dont need that, I need to schedule tasks using data that stored in database MySQL, and immediately to execute this in time. Also database can be extended by new dates. So Celery should be aware about that immidiatly. You sugest to use static concret date. It is not suitable for me.

Comment: You could hook into the `save` or connect to the `post_save` signal, and call your publish task via `apply_async(eta=instance.publish_date)`. Of course the task itself needs to recheck if the date hasn't changed.

Comment: Do you mean aync call task directly after submitting form?

Comment: That is possible too, hooking to save is more secure though, e.g. if publishing dates are changed any other way, like through the console.

Comment: Is it stored to queue directly? Can you share an example?

Answer (score 1):

you can execute tasks by using paramater `eta` on `apply_async()` (refer to http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#eta-and-countdown)

eta parameter must be in datetime format, so it will be run on the exact millisecond precision.

I recommend that you use ORM, so the datetime data type from your database will convert automatically by ORM :D

let's say we have an **Article** model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

and then our **tasks** module:

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def set_published(*args, **kwargs):
    article = Article.objects.get(id=args[1])
    article.published = True
    article.save()

    print("article %d has been published" % args[1])
```

Save the new article and call **set_published** with **ETA**+1minute

```
article = Article(title='This is a new article', published=False, created_date=datetime.utcnow())
article.save()

delta = timedelta(minutes=1)
set_published.apply_async(args=(article.id,), eta=article.created_date + delta)
```

Comment: edited ! this is might be the simple solution, you can use signal (like post_save) in model for calling the set_published function so it will be invoked everytime Article saved