# Execute task on specific time in Django

Tags: python, django, celery, cron-task

I have to execute a task at a specific time, which is specified by the user.
This will not be fix time...
It will be according to user...

On that time I have to execute my task...

To achieve this I tried to use django-cron also tried to use django-crontab...

But in both case either we have to specify cron details in *settings.py* or we've to execute *runcron* commands.

I also checked django-celery (I don't have any idea about celery much. I  may be wrong).

In celery we have to specify time while defining task...

Can any one help me how can I do this...

I am using django as a backend...

Comment: You'll have to use celery. It's the best thing to run scheduled tasks. Please refer to this documentation and tutorial provided on their website : http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47489274/how-to-execute-tasks-in-celery-using-datetime-from-mysql/47491358#47491358 find the delta time and use it as `eta`

Answer (score 1):

To execute a task at specified date and time you can use `eta` attribute of `apply_async` while calling task as mentioned in docs(http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#eta-and-countdown)

`your_task.apply_async(kwargs={}, eta="your_send_time")`

```
## Note: your_send_time should be of type `datetime`.
```