# Schedule emails on a specific time using Django and celery

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, celery, django-celery

This is the use case I am looking for :

- User will register on my application
- It is a note making and remainder application
- While creating remainder users will enter the time my application wants to send user an email at that time
- I have to use celery for the same
  I read several posts and stack overflow answers but didn't get proper answer for the same.

My application is written in Django.

Answer (score 1):

When a user creates a new reminder just schedule a send email task in celery. Note that this is a simple solution but it will make it hard for the user to change notification time after creating it.

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47633835/7888973):

> To execute a task at a specified date and time you can use eta attribute of apply_async while calling task as mentioned in [docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#eta-and-countdown)

> `your_task.apply_async(kwargs={}, eta="your_send_time")`

A different solution is to have a task running every 1 minute which will check in DB if there are any emails to be sent. You don't have to use Celery for that. Cron-like lib should do the trick. For example [schedule lib](https://github.com/dbader/schedule) or [django-cron](https://github.com/Tivix/django-cron) or [Django Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60489028/7888973)

---

Edit: [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51427885/7888973) says you should not use dbader/schedule with Django.

Comment: Thanks man this worked